# Data Factory - Data Flow REST Paging

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having some hard times with REST Source pagination into ADF Dataflows.

Let's start from the beginning. I can **successfully** deal with paginated requests into **regular copy pipeline**, even with a confusing UI:

[image]

The generated code correctly matches the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/236150/how-to-perform-pagination-in-azure-data-factory-us.html):

```
{

    "name": "Paging Copy",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "RestSource",
            "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
            "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010",
            "requestMethod": "GET",
            "paginationRules": {
                "AbsoluteUrl": "$['d'].['__next']",
                "supportRFC5988": "true"
            }
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "JsonSink",
            "storeSettings": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
            },
            "formatSettings": {
                "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
            }
        },
        "enableStaging": false
    }
}
```

Running this kind of activity, it succesffully runs iterating through the pages:

[image]

So far, so good. Now, let's switch to a **Dataflow**:

This is the Source configuration:

[image]

With its code:

```
source(output(
        body as (d as ({__next} as string, results as ({__metadata} [...]
        headers as [string,string]
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    timeout: 30,
    requestInterval: 100,
    queryParameters: ['$format' -> 'json'],
    paginationRules: ['AbsoluteUrl' -> '$.d.__next'],
    responseFormat: ['type' -> 'json', 'documentForm' -> 'singleDocument']) ~> PagedSource
```

I tried different runs with different configurations for the `paginationRules` **property but it seems not to take effect on the pagination which does not iterates through the pages**.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this. Im also pretty much blocked by this.

Comment: Hello Ashish. Unfortunately no. Twitter Azure Support encouraged me to open a service request. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this situation but figured out how to make it works !

I use a inline REST linked service but I think that will work the same for dataset.

In my source output I have declared the reference of my next link label @odata.nextLink :

```
output(
    body as ({@odata.context} as string, {@odata.nextLink} as string, value as (...),
    headers as [string,string]
)
```

And there is my paginationRules config :

```
paginationRules: ['supportRFC5988' -> 'true', 'absoluteUrl' -> 'body.{@odata.nextLink}'],
```

I think dataflow need the references of the field directly, so I used "{" and "}"

Plus, no need the use the "$" because we use "body"

Hope it'll help, have a good day !